# Error storing NSButton IBOutlet name in array then accessing array to setImage on NSButton

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsarray, nsbutton

Help please. I have 4 NSButtons in my window (configured as Gradient style) and depending on user input I make the color of the button one of four different colors ( via setImage using .png files).  My code, which works fine is:

```
if ([[ranColors objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"red"]) {
    [color1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"]];
}
else if ([[ranColors objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"yellow"]) {
    [color1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Yellow.png"]];
}
else if ([[ranColors objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"blue"]) {
    [color1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Blue.png"]];
}
else {
    [color1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"]];
}
```

I repeat this code 4 times for the 4 buttons (color1, color2, color3 and color4). ranColors is an array that holds the user color selection.

I am trying to simplify the code by using an NSArray to hold the button IBOutlet names: color1, color2, color3 and color4 and then using a for loop to interate through the 4 cycles. Here is the code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x) {
if ([[ranColors objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"red"]) {
    [[revealPositions objectAtIndex:x] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"]];
    }
else if ([[ranColors objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"yellow"]) {
    [[revealPositions objectAtIndex:x] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Yellow.png"]];
    }
else if ([[ranColors objectAtIndex:x] isEqualToString:@"blue"]) {
    [[revealPositions objectAtIndex:x] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Blue.png"]];
    }
else {
    [[revealPositions objectAtIndex:x] setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"]];
    }
}
```

I am getting the error: [__NSCFConstantString setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100006098. The error is occurring when I read the array element and then try to setImage to the correct file. It appears that I cannot store the IBOutlet name for the button in an array and then access that name and set a property for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would set the string to be same as the name of the file you can set all the colors without having a loop.

```
[color1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[ranColors objectAtIndex:0]]]];
[color2 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[ranColors objectAtIndex:1]]]];
[color3 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[ranColors objectAtIndex:2]]]];
[color4 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[ranColors objectAtIndex:3]]]];
```

Are you sure that `[revealPositions objectAtIndex:x]` stores a `NSButton`  Post the code where you are storing UIButton in that array for clarification.

Post back if it worked out or not.

Comment: That's great!  Please accept the answer.  Happy Coding!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do that.